# Data Binding In WPF

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, binding

I have a an instance of class A;

```
class A
{
    ICollection<B> collec.....
}

class B
{
   C propC....;
}
class C
{
     string Name;
}
```

I pass instance as the datacontext to a Window and had set collec as ItemCollectionSource for the grid. Is it possible to display the Name property of C in the DataGrid. Other properties are set if i give the Binding Property.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested properties can be referenced within a binding expression as such...

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding propC.Name} />
```

...where I'm assuming `propC` is indeed a publicly exposed property. You will also need to make sure that `Name` is also a publicly exposed property.

Comment: Thanks..Yes all my properties are public. i din mention. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Make `C.Name` a property rather than a field, and bind on propC.Name

Answer (score 0):

You are using private fields currently, try it with a public property instead.

```
class C
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```